# Function to check/correct commission levels (If-Then-ElseIf, etc.)

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to design a function that allows me to input closing prices of sales for the past month and the commission charged on the deals, then returns to me "LOW", "HIGH", or "OK" based on how the deals match up with our office's commission chart.

For example, if a deal goes through for $25,000 and a 2% commission is recorded, the function should return "HIGH" based on the chart below.

```
Up to $49,999           1.50%
$50,000- $99,999             1.25%
$100,000-$199,999        0.85%
$200,000-$399,999        0.75%
$400,000-$699,999        0.50%
$700,000-$999,999        0.30%
$1,000,000-$1,499,999    0.20%
$1,500,000 and above        0.10%
```

The code I have so far is as follows; I've only shared the first row because that's what I've been testing. There are more duplicate sections with different numbers to mirror the levels of the chart.

Function FeeChecker(x, y)

```
If 50000 > x > 0 Then

    If y > 1.5 Then FeeChecker = "HIGH"
    ElseIf y < 1.5 Then FeeChecker = "LOW"
    ElseIf y = 1.5 Then FeeChecker = "OKAY"
    End If

End Function
```

(Full disclosure, it's been a while since I've used VBA at all, so go easy on me if I'm making an obvious mistake) To this point I can get it to return "LOW" and "OKAY" with no issue, but when I use a higher commission rate, it returns the number 0 instead of "HIGH". What do I need to add/change? TIA

Comment: You can try to change your first if to: if x > 50000 then

Answer (score 0):

You might need to put the `FeeChecker = "HIGH"` code (and same for LOW and OKAY) on separate lines. The syntax putting the `Then` part on the same line as the `If` part does not have a corresponding `End If`. I haven't tested the change, it's the first thing I'd do:

```
If y > 1.5
    Then FeeChecker = "HIGH"
ElseIf y < 1.5
    Then FeeChecker = "LOW"
Else ' y = 1.5
    Then FeeChecker = "OKAY"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is using `Select Case` statements as follows:

```
Function FeeChecker(Deal As Double, Commission As Double)

    Select Case Deal     

        Case Is <= 49999            
            FeeChecker = IIf(Commission < 1.5, "Low", IIf(Commission > 1.5, "High", "Okay"))

        Case Is <= 99999            
            FeeChecker = IIf(Commission < 1.25, "Low", IIf(Commission > 1.25, "High", "Okay"))            

    End Select

End Function
```

You can add the additionally case statements to fit your commission table.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes it appears to want you to FeeChecker = "High" on it's own line
2) You are missing an End If. Two Ifs. Only one End If.
3) Why use the outer loop and hardcode 50000 and 1.5? Why not put the data in a table in the Excel spreadsheet? Make it a tax table format so you can use lookup functions (say match with last parameter 1) that aren't looking for an exact value. Then you only need the inner If statement.

```
Function FeeChecker(x,y)
    ' Lookup y value based on x from table and store as commPct
    If y > commPct Then
        FeeChecker = "HIGH"
    ElseIf y < commPct Then
        FeeChecker = "LOW"
    ElseIf y = commPct Then
        FeeChecker = "OKAY"
    End If
End Function
```